# Implicitly wrapped trait with type member does not compile

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter, type-alias, type-members

The following does not compile because of the last line:

```
object ImplicitWrappedTraitWithType {

  trait Wrapper[+T] {
    def unwrap: T
  }

  object Wrapper {
    def apply[T](implicit w: Wrapper[T]): Wrapper[T] = w
  }

  trait IO[In] {
    type Out

    def out: Out
  }

  implicit def decoder[In]: Wrapper[IO[In] {type Out = String}] = new Wrapper[IO[In] {type Out = String}] {
    override def unwrap: IO[In] {type Out = String} = new IO[In] {
      override type Out = String
      override val out: Out = "yeah"
    }
  }

  val wrap = Wrapper[IO[String]]
  val io: IO[String] = wrap.unwrap
  val out: String = io.out //actual type: unwrap.Out
}
```

What can I do to convince the compiler that `val out` is a `String`?

---

***Pre-edit - ignore this***

**Example 1** - this does not compile:

```
object ImplicitWrappedTraitWithType {
  class Wrapper[T]
  object Wrapper {
    def apply[T](implicit w: Wrapper[T]): Wrapper[T] = w
  }
  trait IO[In] {
    type Out
  }
  implicit def decoder[In]: Wrapper[IO[In] {type Out = String}] = null

//client code
  Wrapper[IO[String]]
}
```

**Example 2** - whereas this does:

```
object ImplicitWrappedTraitWithType {
  class Wrapper[T]
  object Wrapper {
    def apply[T](implicit w: Wrapper[T]): Wrapper[T] = w
  }
  trait IO[In] {
    type Out
  }
  implicit def decoder[In]: Wrapper[IO[In]] = null

//client code
  Wrapper[IO[String]]
}
```

In the client code I don't know what the type of `Out` will be, but I need to be able to access it when I extract an instance of `IO` from `Wrapper` (code for that not shown).

*How must 'Example 1' be changed for this to compile, while retaining the Out parameter in a way that is visible for the client code.*

(Please comment if this formulation is unclear)

Comment: The Aux pattern might help here: https://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need two minor edits to your code.

```
trait Wrapper[+T] {
  def unwrap: T
}

object Wrapper {
  def apply[T](implicit w: Wrapper[T]): w.type = w
}

trait IO[In] {
  type Out

  def out: Out
}

implicit def decoder[In]: Wrapper[IO[In] {type Out = String}] = new Wrapper[IO[In] {type Out = String}] {
  override def unwrap: IO[In] {type Out = String} = new IO[In] {
    override type Out = String
    override val out: Out = "yeah"
  }
}

val wrap = Wrapper[IO[String]]
val io = wrap.unwrap
val out: String = io.out
```

The most important is to change the return type of the `apply` method to `w.type`. That way the full type of `w` (including all refinements) is retained. If you write `Wrapper[T]` as return type and you ask for a `Wrapper[T]` for `T` equal to `IO[String]`, you will get a `Wrapper[IO[String]]` and all extra knowledge like `{type Out = String}` will be lost.

Second: in `val io: IO[String] = wrap.unwrap` you say that `io` is an `IO[String]`. Again, all extra knowledge is lost. So just let the compiler infer the type of `io`.

Another thing: if you don't want `Wrapper` to be covariant in `T`, you can just leave off the variance annotation and change your `apply` method.

```
trait Wrapper[T] {
  def unwrap: T
}

object Wrapper {
  def apply[T](implicit w: Wrapper[_ <: T]): w.type = w
}
```

That way the compiler still knows it has to look for *a subtype of* `IO[String]` if you call `Wrapper.apply[IO[String]]`. Because `IO[String]{type out = String}` is a subtype of `IO[String]`, they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you are trying to achieve, but does that solve your problem?
(note the -T in Wrapper)

```
object ImplicitWrappedTraitWithType {
  class Wrapper[-T]
  object Wrapper {
    def apply[T](implicit w: Wrapper[T]): Wrapper[T] = w
  }
  trait IO[In] {
    type Out
  }
  implicit def decoder[In]: Wrapper[IO[In]] = null


}
import ImplicitWrappedTraitWithType._

trait IOString[In] extends IO[In] { 
  type Out = String
}
//client code
Wrapper[IOString[Int]]
```

I won't put any restriction on the `Out` type when trying to find an implicit decoder for it.

Whether the user defines it's own decoder and in that case you don't care about `In` and `Out`, or you have some basic decoders and you provide it, eg: IO[Int, String], IO[Int, Boolean], etc.

Comment: -T didn't do anything regarding compilation. However it made me try +T as well which 'worked' - sorta. I'm updating the question a bit although I'm beginning to suspect there's no solution to my problem.

Comment: Maybe you have changed your code in the meantime. The example you post here which I refactored a little bit won't work with T or +T, only with -T.

Anyway, I see you took another route and found I better approach. Have fun! ;-)